# FileReader reads only one file when multiple dropped

Tags: javascript, file, reader

I am coding and form with  and struggle tor ead each file. What i am getting is onlz one file being read.

Code below does log each iteration (console.log(i)), but does read and log only the last file, no matter what if read as dataURL or as Text

```
fileInput.on('change',function(){

    var files= fileInput.prop('files');
    console.log(files);

    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

       var reader = new FileReader();
      console.log(i);
      reader.onload = function(){

          console.log(reader.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

    }

  });
```

I need each of multiple file to be logged in console. Thanks in advace

Comment: Just change `var reader = new FileReader();` to `let reader = new FileReader();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `let` instead of `var` for `reader` variable, since `var` is function scoped.

Answer (score 1):

use `let` instead of `var` to properly scope the variable to the loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { // Use let here

  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log(i);
  reader.onload = function() {

    console.log(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

}
```

Comment: Hi, infortunately the same result. Thought without being busy with other files exception. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget the `multiple` attribute on the `input` element?

Comment: Hi, no i did not ... I getting exception: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs.(…)